# How to run Britbox on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: video, streaming-video, web-browsers

I was wondering how can I watch Britbox https://www.britbox.co.uk/ on a Raspberry Pi 4?

Currently, the video output is not running in chromium. I have tried increasing the gpu to 256 and this had no effect. I have also tried Firefox ESR and hit the same issue there with the video output not running.

I have installed Kodi but not managed to find a plugin to use Britbox.

https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=350990

Answer (score 0):

I successfully watch Britbox on Chromium (Pi4,64bit OS). I note that the question in the OP is a year old, so maybe compatibility has improved since.